# How to access a variable in a function and display it in the template - Angular 2 Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Beginner with both NativeScript and Typescript. I am trying to access a variable that gets declared in a function, so I can display it in the view. If thats not possible, then how should I fix it

TypeScript code:

```
onValueEvent(result) {
    var cardtitle = result.value.title; // variable I am trying to access in view
    console.log(cardtitle); // logs expected value
}
getCardData(cardID: string) {
    firebase.addValueEventListener(this.onValueEvent, "/cards/" + cardID).then(
        function (listenerWrapper) {
            var path = listenerWrapper.path;
            var listeners = listenerWrapper.listeners;
        });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you don´t use a arrow function

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
cardtitle: any;

onValueEvent(result) {
  this.cardtitle = result.value.title; // variable I am trying to access in view
  console.log(this.cardtitle); // logs expected value
}
getCardData(cardID: string) {
    firebase.addValueEventListener(this.onValueEvent, "/cards/" + cardID).then(
        function (listenerWrapper) {
            var path = listenerWrapper.path;
            var listeners = listenerWrapper.listeners;
        });
}
```

and then you should be able to access `cardtitle` from the template with `{{ cardtitle }}`

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to access cardtitle. Applying the same solution for cardtitle it crashes: TypeError: Cannot set property `cardtitle` of undefined

Comment: I have updated the answer some mins ago, you have to declare `cardtitle: any` before assigning it

Comment: when doing so i get "Calling js method onDataChange failed TypeError: Cannot set property 'cardtitle' of undefined"

Comment: that's weird... maybe creating a plunker or sharing a bit more code would help. As other said too, this should work

Comment: If you use arrow function then it will preserve the meaning of `this` and you will be able to access `this.cardtitle` . This has nothing to do with НativeScript but with the way TypeScript works. Change the `then` not to use function but an arrow https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to display a local variable of a function in the DOM. Instead declare the variable in your class and access that variable within your function using the `this.variable_name` notation. You can use that variable in the DOM through interpolation like `{{variable_name}}` or `this.variable_name`

Comment: When declare it in the class and access it in the function: I get " Calling js method onDataChange failed
TypeError: Cannot set property 'cardtitle' of undefined"

Comment: How have you declared cardtitle as?

Comment: declared as any